# Hibernate 4 and Postgres 9: Criteria.list() is throwing exception

Tags: hibernate, postgresql-9.1

I've met with strange issue involving postgres jdbc driver version 9.1-901.jdbc3.
Here is my dao

```
  @Override
    public List<Products> getProductsListByIds(List<String> ids, Integer storeId) {
    Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(Products.class)
    .add(Restrictions.eq("storeId", storeId))
    .add(Restrictions.in("productId", ids))
    .add(Restrictions.isNotEmpty("createdAt"))
    .add(Restrictions.isNotEmpty("updatedAt"))
    .add(Restrictions.isNotNull("id"))
    return criteria.list();
    }
```

When I run SQL statement it returns 96 results and I am guessing hibernate has fixed list size of 100 (that is how many ids I am passing Restrictions) and returns 4 null objects in the list.
As the result postgres jdbc driver fails when it tries to map null into timestamp with following exception:

```
org.hibernate.exception.DataException: Bad value for type timestamp : 
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:134)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractResultSetProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractResultSetProxyHandler.java:108)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy44.getTimestamp(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.TimestampTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(TimestampTypeDescriptor.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:261)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:257)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:247)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:332)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2873)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1668)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1600)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1500)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:712)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:940)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:910)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:341)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2516)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2502)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2332)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2327)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1621)
    at org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:374)
    at com.insparq.insparqsvc.dao.impl.StoresDAOImpl.getProductsListByIds(StoresDAOImpl.java:115)
    at com.insparq.insparqsvc.service.impl.StoreServiceImpl.getProductsListByIds(StoreServiceImpl.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy38.getProductsListByIds(Unknown Source)
    at com.insparq.jobserver.service.impl.ScheduledJobServiceImpl.normalizeProducts(ScheduledJobServiceImpl.java:446)
    at com.insparq.jobserver.service.impl.ScheduledJobServiceImpl.parseCSV(ScheduledJobServiceImpl.java:415)
    at com.insparq.jobserver.service.impl.ScheduledJobServiceImpl.generateProductsCSV(ScheduledJobServiceImpl.java:214)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:198)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy39.generateProductsCSV(Unknown Source)
    at com.insparq.jobserver.test.ScheduledJobTest.processJob(ScheduledJobTest.java:173)
    at com.insparq.jobserver.test.ScheduledJobTest.test(ScheduledJobTest.java:111)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:172)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:104)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:70)
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Bad value for type timestamp : 
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.TimestampUtils.loadCalendar(TimestampUtils.java:246)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.TimestampUtils.toTimestamp(TimestampUtils.java:321)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.getTimestamp(AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.java:437)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.getTimestamp(AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.java:2446)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingResultSet.getTimestamp(DelegatingResultSet.java:229)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractResultSetProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractResultSetProxyHandler.java:104)
    ... 82 more
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Timestamp has neither date nor time
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.TimestampUtils.loadCalendar(TimestampUtils.java:243)
    ... 91 more
```

Is there any way to tell hibernate to load only results it gets and do not fill rest of the elements with nulls?

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate doesn't have fixed list size, it just executes query.
It can't convert row value to timestamp. May be the row have date type.
I had similar error in mysql when row contains zero value(00/00/00...) after I had set not null restriction in database.

Comment: I am not sure what is going on, but looks like it is the problem with driver. I updated to version 9.2 but still get the error. When I run simple select it returns data fine. So just for sake of it I've changed column from not null to null and then set created_at to null. Everything went fine. Then I updated created_at using to_timestamp function. It started to fail again. I am completely lost here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think [isNotEmpty](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/api/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html#isNotEmpty%28java.lang.String%29) is a valid restriction of a timestamp field like `createdAt`.

As per the documentation, it is application to only collection property.

> Constrain a collection valued property to be non-empty

You are supposed to use [isNotNull](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/api/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html#isNotNull%28java.lang.String%29) here.

```
public List<Products> getProductsListByIds(List<String> ids, Integer storeId) {
    Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(Products.class)  
        .add(Restrictions.eq("storeId", storeId))
        .add(Restrictions.in("productId", ids))
        .add(Restrictions.isNotNull("createdAt"))
        .add(Restrictions.isNotNull("updatedAt"))
        .add(Restrictions.isNotNull("id"))
    return criteria.list();
}
```

*Another side note: Postgres driver 9.1.901 seems to some series performance problems, I recommend to move to the latest version 9.1.902 or 9.1.903*